# How do I get multiple images from a single string

Tags: php, string, image, function

I've looked around and haven't found a answer that did it for me. I don't want all the images from an HTML page. I just want all the images from a single string.

On a page, I'm using two different strings. I want all the images that are within the second image. I want to loop them into a carousel.

I've looked around a bit and this is what I got:

```
function GetImgString($plaatje){

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$plaatje, $result);

$house = $result[0];

$i = 1;

    $output = '<div class="carousel-inner">';

        foreach ( $house as $houses ) {

                if ($i == 1) {
                    $output.= '<div class="item active">';
                }else{
                    $output.= '<div class="item">';
                }


                $output.= 

                        $house.'
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                ';


            $i++;
        }

    $output .= '</div>';

    return $house;}
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img src="images/Huizen/huis-3.jpg" alt="" />
    [1] => <img src="images/Huizen/huis-4.jpg" alt="" />
)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Where this `$huis` variable is supposed to come from?

Comment: `$huis` is what? Correct, it's an invalid argument, since it's empty.

Comment: $huis = $result[0];, sorry forgot to put this there as well. I got the images out in an array. They were all in $result[0];

Comment: This error says that $huis is not an array.... print_r($huis) in your page and you could notice that... If you also comment the value of $huis we could also help you.

Comment: I would also recommend you to use the variables written in english.. maybe some other programmer will need to modify your code and he will need to understand what you wanted to do..

Comment: If you want to iterate over the `results` array, why don't you use `results` instead of only its first element. Also, the regex for matching an img is flawed; it won't match `<img alt=">" src="pic.png">`. In addition, I have a strong suspicion that you have mixed up the words "huis" and "huizen" somewhere, which wouldn't happen if you translated them to English...

Comment: Mr Lister, I've edited it to english

Answer (score 0):

I assume, when you do the regexp, in your results, there are the 2 images.

You are start to building your output into a variable, calles `$output`, but you return with `$house`, what contain the 2 result from `preg_match`.

So you can try with this:

```
function GetImgString($plaatje) {
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $plaatje, $result);
    $houses = $result[0];
    $houses = str_ireplace('<', '&lt', $house);
    $houses = str_ireplace('>', '&gt', $house);
    $i = 1;
    $output = '<div class="carousel-inner">';
    foreach ($houses as $house) {
        $class = ' class="item"';
        if ($i === 1) {
            $class = ' class="item active"';
        }
        $output.= '<div '.$class.'>';
        $output.=   $house . '
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>' . "\n";
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: This will also just output the first image.

I returned $house to get the content of that array. 

Basically what I need is to get all images from a string, and put them in a loop like $output

Comment: Is your images in the `$house` variable? Is `$house` an array?

Comment: Yes. But the only problem is that when I use a foreach, it will only output the first image. @lolka_bolka

Comment: Do you have a live example site?